# makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair1, pair2) will not resolve for some reason

Tags: android, android-animation, androidx

I am making a scene transition between two activities, where I am swapping the location of the two views. I am using makeSceneTransitionAnimation. But anytime I try to add a pair it gives cannot resolve method

It works perfectly fine if I do just one view like this makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, m4, "swapTransistion") but anytime time I add a pair it does not work, I have added a sample code of it below where I cannot get it to resolve

```java
intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Pair<ImageView, String> p1 = Pair.create((ImageView) m4, "swapTransition");
Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create((View) m2, "blueTransition");

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,p1,p2);

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Edit: I understand that by changing it to ActivityOptions instead of Compat it will work. But I am adding support for older versions of android and using the support libraries as I do not want this to crash for older Android version

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way , using `ActivityOptions` :

```
View view1 = m4;
View view2 = m2;   
ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                            Pair.create(view1, "swapTransition"),
                            Pair.create(view2, "blueTransition"));
```

**Edit :**

here how i manage to transform my example using ActivityOptionsCompat

```
  android.support.v4.util.Pair[] pairs = new  android.support.v4.util.Pair[3];
                    pairs[0] = new  android.support.v4.util.Pair(sharedView, transitionName);
                    pairs[1] = new  android.support.v4.util.Pair(sharedView2, transitionName2);
                    pairs[2] = new  android.support.v4.util.Pair(sharedView2, transitionName3);
                    ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,pairs);
```

and it works now just use your example , have a good evening !

Comment: Try it with my method , i never used ActivityOptionsCompact , but it works fine with me and i havr three sharedview

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified a bit more. I know activityoptions work however since I need to support other version specifically older version I opted to use the support library